# OrbitControls : updating position and World/View scale of a 'helper'

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm trying to manage a 3Dobject that visualize the controls target in order to make rotation and zoom more immediatly understandable ...

[**I've made a sample here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jeum/w6AB3/3/) with an AxisHelper which is supposed to indicate the target and to keep the same size. In OrbitControls.js there are comments on each line I've added.

As you can see if you pan and zoom (right click and scroll) it manages cursors too, but the 'helper' has two problems :

- the position and scale of the helper is set after the renders, that why it seems to be somewhat elastic ... And if I place the position/scale updates into the scope.update() function that's the same thing.
- the function bellow scales the helper to a constant size, it computes a World/View scale at a defined point (the control's target) from a unit vector. But it seems it's not the good solution because when you scroll to the max zoom the helper is growing.

  ```
  var point = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 );
  point = point.applyMatrix4( scope.object.matrixWorld );
  var scale = point.distanceTo( scope.target );
  helper.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);
  ```

So if you have an idea to achieve this you are welcome ...

Answer (score 0):

i'm currently developing something similar with threejs and i think that:

1. I can't see the demo, my proxy not allow it.
2. I think that is correct...if the object helper is a mesh or a sprite added to the scene when orbit controls zoom the camera became more near to the objects in the scene, the objects dimension remain the same.

Comment: Of course it would be simpler with a sprite, but the goal would be to show orientation. I use an Axishelper but with a mesh I would get the same 'scale' problem ...